# LRU Cache Evict method implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, caching, lru, evict

If we are implementing a `LRU` cache using `HashMap` and `DoublyLinkedList`, What is the best way to implement `evict()` method with `O(1)` time complexity?

Comment: `java.util.LinkedHashMap` has some traits to impl a LRU, I updated the answer a bit, maybe you would consider whether use it or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LinkedList` from `Java` didn't expose the `Node` type *(which is a `private static` inner class)*.

So you can't remove it in in `O(1)`, because a sequential scan is required.

To get `O(1)`, you need to be able to access the `Node` type, so that could remove it without scan.

You have to write it by yourself. Fortunately, a `doubly linked list` is relatively easy to write, and it's a pretty beneficial & fun task to do.

---

### How to remove with a given `Node`?

Refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54593530

The method `LinkedList.java` -> `removeNode()` remove a given node, without sequential scan.

The code in this answer is for a singly linked list, the `remove` for a doubly linked list is even simpler in some case.

**Tips:**

- If the given node is the end node in linked list, then you need the previous node too.
  But that's for `singly linked list`, for a `doubly linked node`, the node itself contains the previous node, so you don't have to pass previous node to the `removeNode()` method.

---

**BTW**

- Why it's beneficial?
  `linked list` is the most basic structure *(except `array` and `bits`)*, that some other very basic structures could built base on.
  e.g both `queue` and `stack` could be implemented easily with a `linked list`.
- Concurrent access
  `java.util.LinkedList` is not thread-safe, your LRU might needs some concurrent control, but I'm not sure.
  If need, then `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedDeque` is a good example to refer to.

---

### @Update  `LinkedHashMap`

`java.util.LinkedHashMap`, is a combination of hashtable & doubly linked list.

**Mechanism:**

- It extends `HashMap` to get the `O(1)` complexity for the common operations.
- And use `doubly linked list` to keep track of insertion order.
  `head` is the eldest item, and `tail` is the newest item.

It can be used to impl some kind of cache, though I am not sure will it be fully qualified for your requirement.